# Is there any API or website that could colorcode my Java codes and transform it into html?

Tags: java, html, post

I have a piece of Java code that I want to post on my website.

The code looks like this:

```
class Integers {
  public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    int c; //declaring a variable

  /* Using for loop to repeat instruction execution */

    for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }
  }
}
```

In order to transform it into a good looking HTML and post it on my website i need to write the following:

```
<div class="geshifilter">
<pre class="java geshifilter-java" style="font-family:monospace;"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">class</span> Integers <span style="color: #009900;">{</span>
  <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">public</span> <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">static</span> <span style="color: #000066; font-weight: bold;">void</span> main<span style="color: #009900;">(</span><span style="color: #003399;">String</span><span style="color: #009900;">[</span><span style="color: #009900;">]</span> arguments<span style="color: #009900;">)</span> <span style="color: #009900;">{</span>
    <span style="color: #000066; font-weight: bold;">int</span> c<span style="color: #339933;">;</span> <span style="color: #666666; font-style: italic;">//declaring a variable</span>
&nbsp;
  <span style="color: #666666; font-style: italic;">/* Using for loop to repeat instruction execution */</span>
&nbsp;
    <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">for</span> <span style="color: #009900;">(</span>c <span style="color: #339933;">=</span> <span style="color: #cc66cc;">1</span><span style="color: #339933;">;</span> c <span style="color: #339933;">&lt;=</span> <span style="color: #cc66cc;">10</span><span style="color: #339933;">;</span> c<span style="color: #339933;">++</span><span style="color: #009900;">)</span> <span style="color: #009900;">{</span>
      <span style="color: #003399;">System</span>.<span style="color: #006633;">out</span>.<span style="color: #006633;">println</span><span style="color: #009900;">(</span>c<span style="color: #009900;">)</span><span style="color: #339933;">;</span>
    <span style="color: #009900;">}</span>
  <span style="color: #009900;">}</span>
<span style="color: #009900;">}</span></pre></div>
```

There is too much hassle doing this. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SyntaxHighlighter. It should do exactly what you are looking for: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 1):

Put all your code within `<pre class="prettyprint">` or `<code class="prettyprint">` elements and add the **google-code-prettify** JavaScript plugin to your webpage. Here is the link to the tutorial:

http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html